# using String with UIStepper - Swift

Tags: swift, uistepper

i have a label and a UIStepper, i need to increase the number of that label without lossing the letters ( Kd ) . my label will be like this "5.000 Kd" and when i increase the number i don't want to loss the ( Kd ) label.

this is my code

```
import UIKit
import GMStepper

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    
    @IBOutlet var stepper: GMStepper!
    @IBOutlet var price: UILabel!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
    
    
    @IBAction func stepper(_ sender: Any) {
        
        let label = "5.000 Kd" as NSString
        price.text! = String(label.doubleValue * stepper.value)
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Kepp in another variable the current as `Double` value, and use this one to calculate the new value. Then create the label text from it adding the `Kd`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are hard-coding the string contents of the label, just maintain a numeric value and rebuild the label contents each time that value changes:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var stepper: GMStepper!
    @IBOutlet var priceLabel: UILabel!
    var price: Double = 5.0
    
    @IBAction func stepper(_ sender: Any) {
        let newValue =  price * stepper.value
        //Format the price with 3 decimal places
        let priceString = String(format: "%.3f", newValue) 

        Construct a string with the formatted price and " Kd" and put it in the label
        priceLabel.text = "\(priceString) Kd")
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks its work but the problem now it multiply by 1000 ! i want it to be like this operation String(label.doubleValue * stepper.value)

Comment: It multiplies by 1000? That makes no sense. Describe what you want it to do in words? (for example, "The label value should be the price times the current stepper value")

Comment: See the edits I made to my answer. It looks to me like you want the price to be a fixed value of 5.0, and you want the price label to be `5 * stepper` value.

Comment: thanks its work :) thanks alooooooooooooooooooot

Comment: If an answer solves your problem, you should click the checkbox to accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using NumberFormatter to format currency:

```
 let cf = NumberFormatter()
 cf.currencyCode = "KWD"
 cf.numberStyle = .currency
 cf.string(from: 5000)
```

That respects the user's Locale.

Comment: and how can i use it in UIStepper ?